# How to feed rows from one model to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

I have 4 tables: proposals, proposal_line_items (proposal_line_items is nested inside proposals) invoices,and invoice_line_items.

I am trying to feed rows created in the proposal_line_items table into invoices when the client approves of each item. I am using a checkbox ( 1 => approved) in the proposal_line_items to determine if it is approved or not.

This is how I set up my invoices controller to make the invoices receive the rows from proposal_line_items.

```
class InvoicesController < ActionController
  def new
    @approved_items = Proposal.find(params[:proposal_id]).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)
  end
end
```

When I try to create the new invoice I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#new Couldn't find Proposal with 'id'= Extracted source (around line #17): 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Controller action:

```
# GET /invoices/new 
def new
  @approved Proposal.find(params[:proposal_id]).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1) 
end
```

Can you please help me solve this issue? Thank you!

**Models:**

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposal_line_items
end
class ProposalLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposal
end
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_line_items
end
class InvoiceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

**Migration files:**

```
class CreateProposalLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :proposal_line_items do |t|
      t.references :proposal, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.integer :approved
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateProposals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :proposals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateInvoiceLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invoice_line_items do |t|
      t.references :invoice, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.integer :approved
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
class CreateInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invoices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
invoices GET    /invoices(.:format)                                     invoices#index POST   /invoices(.:format)                                              invoices#create
new_invoice GET    /invoices/new(.:format)                              invoices#new
edit_invoice GET    /invoices/:id/edit(.:format)                             invoices#edit
invoice GET    /invoices/:id(.:format)                                  invoices#show
PATCH  /invoices/:id(.:format)                                          invoices#update
PUT    /invoices/:id(.:format)                                          invoices#update
DELETE /invoices/:id(.:format)                                          invoices#destroy`

proposal_proposal_line_items POST /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items(.:format)          proposals/proposal_line_items#create

  new_proposal_proposal_line_item GET    /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/new(.:format)      proposals/proposal_line_items#new

 edit_proposal_proposal_line_item GET    /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/:id/edit(.:format) proposals/proposal_line_items#edit

proposal_proposal_line_item GET    /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/:id(.:format)      proposals/proposal_line_items#show

PATCH  /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/:id(.:format)      proposals/proposal_line_items#update

PUT    /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/:id(.:format)      proposals/proposal_line_items#update

DELETE /proposals/:proposal_id/proposal_line_items/:id(.:format)      proposals/proposal_line_items#destroy

proposals GET    /proposals(.:format)                              proposals#index

POST   /proposals(.:format)                                  proposals#create

new_proposal GET    /proposals/new(.:format)  proposals#new

edit_proposal GET    /proposals/:id/edit(.:format)                     proposals#edit

proposal GET    /proposals/:id(.:format)                             proposals#show

PATCH  /proposals/:id(.:format)                              proposals#update

PUT    /proposals/:id(.:format)                              proposals#update

DELETE /proposals/:id(.:format)                              proposals#destroy
```

**update**

**controller**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end
  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end
  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @approved = Proposal.require(:proposal_id).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)
  end
  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:date, :proposal_line_item_id)
    end
end
```

***UPDATE***

**New**

```
<h1>New Invoice</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', invoices_path %>
```

**Form**

```
%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
  <% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :proposal_line_item %><br>
    <%= collection_select( :proposal_line_item, :proposal_line_item_id, Proposal_line_item.all, :id, :date, {}, {:multiple => false}) %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Log Output**

```
Started GET "/invoices/new" for ::1 at 2015-04-09 12:48:00 -0500
Processing by InvoicesController#new as HTML
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: proposal_line_item):
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:23:in `proposal_line_item'
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:17:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (16.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js within layouts/javascript (11.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html (24.2ms)


Started GET "/invoices/new" for ::1 at 2015-04-09 12:48:00 -0500
Processing by InvoicesController#new as HTML
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: proposal_line_item):
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:23:in `proposal_line_item'
  app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:17:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (25.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js within layouts/javascript (11.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/davefogo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.1.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html (23.8ms)
```

Comment: The issue here is that the `proposal_id` you are sending with your request is not valid.  Have you verified that the `Proposal` actually exists, or that you didn't mess up the route?

Comment: I deleted all proposals and created a new one to see if it fixed the error. No luck. Also where can I check if I messed up the route? I tried the p = Proposal.last + p.proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1) in rails c and got a result. Why is this not working?

Comment: I have revised the routes (see above) but cannot find the culprit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like your route is formatted properly, but based on the error that is being returned, it looks like value is `nil`.  Try doing this in your controller and see what happens: `@approved_items = Proposal.find(params.require(:proposal_id])).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)`.  I suspect it will raise an error saying that the required parameter wasn't supplied.

Comment: Now I am getting this as a result of the suggested change: NoMethodError in InvoicesController#new
private method `require' called for #<Class:0x007f8bbfa59a40>. Does this shun new light?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2.0 is what I am running

Comment: Can you update the post with what your controller looks like now?  By making the change that I suggested, it should be making use of http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html but it seems like its not.  There is definitely something odd going on in your setup.

Comment: Your `new` method does not match the content I provided.  Please try again.  You have `Proposal.require(:proposal_id)` where you should have `Proposal.find(params.require(:proposal_id))`

Comment: Now I am getting param is missing or the value is empty: proposal_id . I am sure I have 3 full proposals to fill in.

Comment: That is exactly the error I suspected it would raise.  I think you are not passing in the proposal to that controller.  How are you making the request?

Comment: ie: curl, or some other method?

Comment: I am making the request via the create invoice view

Comment: If I try to do it through rails c I get: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object

Comment: Eugene do you have any thoughts on what might be up?

Comment: Can I see the create invoice view?  I'm thinking the problem is in there.

Comment: Please see update in main question. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I finally see the problem.  I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are making a request to a route with no parameters.  I incorrectly assumed that you were seeing this error when you were submitting the form, you are seeing this error when the form is rendered.  I would suggest updating the route from `/invoices/new` to something along the lines of `/proposal/:proposal_id/invoices/new` and then using this for your controller method:

```
class InvoicesController < ActionController
  def new
    @approved_items = Proposal.find(params.require(:proposal_id)).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)
  end
end
```

You can then use your original view before I suggested modifications.

**Everything below this line is wrong**

The issue here is that you are trying to query a `Proposal`, but the item you are actually passing in to the controller from your form is a `ProposalLineItem`

On this line of your form:

`collection_select( :proposal_line_item, :proposal_line_item_id, Proposal_line_item.all, :id, :date, {}, {:multiple => false})`

You are generating a collection of `ProposalLineItem`s for your form, but there is also a typo in that line of `Proposal_line_item` instead of `ProposalLineItem`

In order to query a `Proposal` in your controller, you need to do one of two things.

**Option 1**

Update your controller to this:

```
class InvoicesController < ActionController
  def new
    @approved_items = proposal ? proposal.proposal_line_items.where(approved: 1) : []
  end

  protected

  def proposal_line_item
    # The way you have your form configured, the params hash will look like this: {"proposal_line_item" => {"proposal_line_item_id" => "some_id"}}
    @_proposal_line_item = ProposalLineItem.find(params.require(:proposal_line_item).require(:proposal_line_item_id))
  end

  def proposal
    proposal_line_item.proposal
  end
end
```

**Option 2**

However given the context of the form, and what your controller is trying to do, it might make more sense to render a collection of `Proposal`s instead of `ProposalLineItem`s.  Perhaps something like this:

```
# in your form
collection_select( :proposal, :proposal_id, Proposal.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => false})
```

And then in your controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ActionController
  def new
    @approved_items = proposal.proposal_line_items.where(approved: 1)
  end

  protected

  def proposal
    Proposal.find(params.require(:proposal).require(:proposal_id))
  end
end
```

Obviously the choice is yours here, but given what it looks like you are trying to do, I would lean towards option 2.

Also FYI, if you want to test out the parameters stuff in a rails console, you will want to do this:

```
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new
=> {}
> params[:proposal_line_item] = {}
=> {}
> params[:proposal_line_item][:proposal_line_item_id] = "asdf"
=> "asdf"
> params.require(:proposal_line_item)
=> {"proposal_line_item_id"=>"asdf"}
> params.require(:proposal_line_item).require(:proposal_line_item_id)
=> "asdf"
```

Comment: Eugene, I am sorry I'am still getting an error for option 1: param is missing or the value is empty: proposal_line_item and for option 2: param is missing or the value is empty: proposal

Comment: Can you paste me some log output from the request that gets sent when you submit the form?

Comment: I am using proposal_proposal_id_invoices_new GET    /proposal/proposal_id/invoices/new(.:format)       proposal/proposal_id/invoices#new as the link_to for "New Invoice" and added to my routes file get "/proposal/proposal_id/invoices/new" but now when I go into the index view for Invoices I am getting this error:  NameError in Invoices#index
Showing /Users/davefogo/Sites/ideapp/app/views/invoices/index.html.erb where line #27 raised:

undefined local variable or method `proposal_proposal_id_invoices_new' for #<#<Class:0x007f7f5c5a5e28>:0x007f7f5c666970>